# phpMyAdmin Error #1649 unknown locale

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I was checking some thing in phpMyAdmin on localhost (WAMP 3.0.6), when suddenly I got locked out with following error:

```
Error

SQL query: Edit

SET lc_messages = 'en_US';

MySQL said:
#1649 - Unknown locale: 'en_US'
```

I was merely just looking around, and I believe the error occurred when I accidentally selected another value in *"Server connection collation"* dropdown under *"General Settings"*, to something else than it's default.

The language is in `my.ini` set to `lc_messages = 'en_US';`

I've tried re-installing WAMP, but without success. The error still shows up every time I try to login to phpMyAdmin. So I'm not sure what the actual problem is.

Thanks.

Comment: Try restarted the server ?

Comment: I assume uninstalling and reinstalling WAMP would act as a server restart? I've also tried restarting All services after reinstall. But doesn't fix the phpMyAdmin error.

Comment: What is your locale

Comment: Did you let the install complete? The last thing done in the install is to run the MYSQL install/initial build

Comment: I don't really understand the error and not quite sure what locale is. I reinstalled with same procedure as I previously installed it where it was working fine earlier. WAMP server icon is also displaying green. My local websites were all working and functional. Only problem was and is, that I couldn't access phpMyAdmin because of that error, to e.g. create a new database.

Comment: You can try clearing your phpMyAdmin cookies (which start with 'pma') and see if that helps.

Comment: Couldn't find any cookies starting with 'pma'. But clearing all cookies has fixed the problem. kinda weird a cookie was causing the error.

Comment: My response was too long for a comment so I turned it in to a full answer for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try clearing your phpMyAdmin cookies (which usually start with 'pma'). Actually, you should only need to clear the 'pma_lang' cookie.

I'm not sure what the root cause of your problem is (maybe your MySQL doesn't have the en_US language pack installed, or maybe it's an old MySQL version or something). It's a bit strange that 'en_US' is defined in my.ini but gives an error when called by phpMyAdmin.

However, by changing the language dropdown, phpMyAdmin now thinks you want to explicitly force a specific language (en_US, in this case, but it could be any locale), so when it connects to MySQL one of the first things it tries to do is force the locale, which causes the error. By clearing the 'pma_lang' cookie, you'll reset the language preference within phpMyAdmin and it should go back to using the system default and not force anything when connecting to MySQL, which will clear up the error message.

Further questions of why this occurred in the first place, if that interests you, should probably be directed to the WAMP folks directly since it kind of seems like a glitch with their kit, but at least this gets your phpMyAdmin working again.

Comment: Cant believe it was that simple, just needed to remove the cookies. Stack Overflow never ceases to amaze me

Comment: @J3STER sure, it's simple in hindsight, but it's also not obvious, which is why we all come here when stumped :-) I'm glad to know it helped.