# AppServ - Error phpmyadmin when you changed uft-8

Tags: phpmyadmin, appserver

I changed my enconding to another one which I dont know it. 
**anyone could help me ?**
I get this message :

[image: PHPMYADMINERROR]

Comment: How did you change the locale in the first place? Through a dropdown in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes, I changed by accident when I was using my PHPmyAdmin. And now? I need in my joomla template

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpMyAdmin Error #1649 unknown locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977950/phpmyadmin-error-1649-unknown-locale)